# I can't figure out why queryClient.getQueryData() returns undefined (React Query)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query, web-frontend

So I have a form component where I store a value and then save it to the server. Saving to server works with useMutation but when I use getQueryData in order to manually update the query state maintained by React Query I get undefined.

Here's the code for the component:

```
import { createAnecdote } from "../requests";
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "react-query";

const AnecdoteForm = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    const newAnecMutation = useMutation(createAnecdote, {
      onSuccess: (newAnecdote) => {
        const anecdotes = queryClient.getQueryData("anecdotes");
        console.log(anecdotes);
        queryClient.setQueryData("anecdotes", anecdotes.concat(newAnecdote));
      },
    });

    const onCreate = async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const content = event.target.anecdote.value;
      event.target.anecdote.value = "";
      newAnecMutation.mutate({ content, votes: 0 });
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>create new</h3>
        <form onSubmit={onCreate}>
          <input name="anecdote" />
          <button type="submit">create</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
};

export default AnecdoteForm;
```

Here's the code for index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import App from "./App";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <App />
    </QueryClientProvider>
);
```

Here's the code for the App component:

```
import AnecdoteForm from "./components/AnecdoteForm";
import Notification from "./components/Notification";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { getAnecdotes } from "./requests";

const App = () => {
    const handleVote = (anecdote) => {
      console.log("vote");
    };

    const result = useQuery("notes", getAnecdotes, {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    });

    if (result.isLoading) {
      return <div>loading data...</div>;
    } else if (result.isError) {
      return (
        <div>anecdote service not available due to problems in the server</div>
      );
    }

    const anecdotes = result.data;

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Anecdote app</h3>

        <Notification />
        <AnecdoteForm />

        {anecdotes.map((anecdote) => (
          <div key={anecdote.id}>
            <div>{anecdote.content}</div>
            <div>
              has {anecdote.votes}
              <button onClick={() => handleVote(anecdote)}>vote</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default App;
```

I was expecting the data from the server:

```
{
    "anecdotes": [
      {
        "content": "If it hurts, do it more often",
        "id": "47145",
        "votes": 0
      },
      {
        "content": "Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!",
        "id": "21149",
        "votes": 0
      },
      {
        "content": "The first 90 percent of the code accounts for the first 90 percent of the development time...The remaining 10 percent of the code accounts for the other 90 percent of the development time.",
        "id": "69581",
        "votes": 0
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there might be a mistake, in your code. In the App component when you call useQuery you're using the query notes" of "anecdotes". This is causing the issue where you're getting data when using queryClient.getQueryData("anecdotes") in the onSuccess callback of your mutation.

To resolve this problem you should make a change to the useQuery call in your App component. Use the query key by updating it to;

const result = useQuery("anecdotes" getAnecdotes, {
refetchOnWindowFocus; false,
});

By replacing "notes" with "anecdotes" as the query key the useQuery hook will correctly. Manage the data from the server. As a result your getQueryData call, in the mutations onSuccess callback should function as expected.